# Xml Deserialize returms null values but xml has values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-parsing

I saw few topics but no one looks like my problem.

Here is my class:

```
namespace Framework.Cielo.Models
{
    [XmlRoot("transacao", Namespace = "http://ecommerce.cbmp.com.br")]
    public class TransactionResponse
    {
        [XmlAttribute("id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("versao")]
        public string Version { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("tid")]
        public string tid { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("pan")]
        public string pan { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("dados-pedido")]
        public EstablishmentOrder Order { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("forma-pagamento")]
        public PaymentMethod PaymentMethod { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("status")]
        public TransactionStatusEnum Status { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("url-retorno")]
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("autenticacao")]
        public Authentication Authentication { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the authentication class

```
namespace Framework.Cielo.Models
{
    [XmlRoot("autenticacao")]
    public class Authentication
    {
        [XmlElement("codigo")]
        public int Code { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("mensagem")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [XmlIgnore]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("data-hora")]
        public string FormattedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss");
            }
            set
            {
                DateTime kdc = DateTime.MinValue;
                DateTime.TryParse(value, out kdc);
                Date = kdc;
            }
        }

        [XmlElement("valor")]
        public int Value { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("lr")]
        public int SecurityLevel { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("arp")]
        public object arp { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("nsu")]
        public object nsu { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is how I deserialize:

```
string serializado = File.ReadAllText("req.xml");
var stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(serializado);
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TransactionResponse));

TransactionResponse preAuthResponse = serializer.Deserialize(stringReader) as TransactionResponse;
```

and here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<transacao versao="1.3.0" id="100" xmlns="http://ecommerce.cbmp.com.br">
  <tid>10069930690A16DF1001</tid>
  <pan>b1SQ6jpKCDt3n9C0dgD/ZkPQ1Bh+7aJESqr/CwP64P0=</pan>
  <dados-pedido>
    <numero>100</numero>
    <valor>29900</valor>
    <moeda>986</moeda>
    <data-hora>2013-10-15T00:57:19.032-03:00</data-hora>
    <descricao/>
    <idioma>PT</idioma>
    <taxa-embarque>0</taxa-embarque>
  </dados-pedido>
  <forma-pagamento>
    <bandeira>mastercard</bandeira>
    <produto>1</produto>
    <parcelas>1</parcelas>
  </forma-pagamento>
  <status>4</status>
  <autenticacao>
    <codigo>4</codigo>
    <mensagem>Transacao sem autenticacao</mensagem>
    <data-hora>2013-10-15T00:57:19.037-03:00</data-hora>
    <valor>29900</valor>
    <eci>0</eci>
  </autenticacao>
  <autorizacao>
    <codigo>4</codigo>
    <mensagem>Transação autorizada</mensagem>
    <data-hora>2013-10-15T00:57:19.041-03:00</data-hora>
    <valor>29900</valor>
    <lr>00</lr>
    <arp>123456</arp>
    <nsu>661215</nsu>
  </autorizacao>
</transacao>
```

When I run this code, all the elements get right, but not `ARP` and `NSU` elements (the last 2 of autorizacao tag)

I really don't know why. This XML comes from a web service and I can't figure out why my deserialize don't work with the 2 last items but works greater with any other element.

Comment: Change ARP and NSU from object to int

Comment: @LostInComputer already done... still the same :(

Comment: What a minute... ARP and NSU are in the autorizacao element but your class is for autenticacao! You may have confused autorizacao with autenticacao.

Comment: @LostInComputer thanks GOD! You're right! :( I'm pretty sure that is something  I was missing. Its 02:31am here in Brazil, i worked since 08am yesterday and I'm really tired :( thanks for your time!

Comment: *Hands leandro a freshly brewed, strong coffee*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with your code and updated following and it works.

1. Commented second last <autenticacao> tag.
2. Rename last tag <autorizacao> to <autenticacao> . May be you are getting wrong xml & last two tags are confusing so I have tried with only one tag.
3. In Authentication class I have changed type of ARP and NSU otherwise we are getting XMlNode  type while deserializing. You can also use string instead of int.

   ```
   [XmlElement("arp")]
   public int arp { get; set; }

   [XmlElement("nsu")]
   public int nsu { get; set; }
   ```